# when call complete activiti task concurrently ,TaskListener for complete task run more than one times

Tags: java, concurrency, activiti

when I call complete method concurrently, `PostpareTaskListener.notify` excute 3 times, how can I make it excute only one time, and other 2 times thorw exception before run in notify method?

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("");

    final ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            processEngine.getTaskService().complete("141209", null);

        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            processEngine.getTaskService().complete("141209", null);

        }
    }).start();

    processEngine.getTaskService().complete("141209", null);
}


public class PostpareTaskListener implements TaskListener{
    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask task) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        task.setVariable("result", "false");

        System.out.println("================post pare ================");

    }
}
```

Comment: does someone has the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get the task state through:

```
task.isSuspended();
```

After all I would expect activit to throw an exception if you try to complete a task which was already completed:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiObjectNotFoundException: Cannot find task with id 141209
```

Maybe setting a variable helps:

```
Boolean executed = (Boolean) task.getVariable("executed");
if (executed) {
    return;
}
task.setVariable("executed", true);
```

Comment: thanks for u answer.
task.isSuspended() is not work.


three threads enter into taskListener and excute notify(DelegateTask task)  concurrently.